# Different results in standard deviation of test set and cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have used KNN for predicting the output power of solar panels. The results are shown below:

```
Test Set:
MAE = 0.044
MSE = 0.004
Standard Deviation = 0.272
```

---

```
 Cross-validation:
   MAE = 0.049
   MSE = 0.005
   Standard Deviation= 0.001
```

Now my question is, why the difference between standard deviations is too much in the test set and cross-validation?

Comment: Standard deviation of what?  I don't see how we can answer this, with the level of information provided here.  I expect the answer will most likely be something related to the details of how you are computing the standard deviation or what you're computing it on.  My experience is that this site works best for conceptual questions. Debugging what is going wrong with ML can be complex and might not be well-suited for this site.

Comment: @D.W. this can be also a conceptual question. I have asked about how it can be so different when the predicted standard deviation is 0.2 but it will be 0.001 when running cross-validation.